# How to merge laravel query into simplier

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have table `questions`

[image]

and `question_options`

[image]

what I used is `return Question::leftJoin('question_options', 'question_options.question_id', '=', 'questions.id')->get();`

and it results like this

**MY RESULT**
[image]

and I want to display like this that is simplify... not looping at all, just added `option` array

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
[
    [
        'name'      =>  'legal_issue',
        'question'  =>  'Description of your current legal issue:',
        'label'     =>  'Please provide as much detail as possible',
        'type'      =>  'text',
    ], [
        'name'      =>  'green_card',
        'question'  =>  'Do you have a Green Card?',
        'label'     =>  'Green Card',
        'type'      =>  'radio',
        'option'    =>  [
                            'Yes', 'No'
                        ]
    ], [
        'name'      =>  'visa_type',
        'question'  =>  'Which type of VISA do you currently have?',
        'label'     =>  'Visa type',
        'type'      =>  'select',
        'option'    =>  [
                            'A-1/A-2','A-1/A-2','A-3 Visa','A-3 Visa','B-1 Visa','B-1 Visa','B-2 Visa','B-2 Visa','C-1 Visa','C-1 Visa','C-1/D Visa','C-1/D Visa','E-1/E-2 Visa','E-1/E-2 Visa','F-1/M-1 Visa','F-1/M-1 Visa','G-1/G-4 Visa','G-1/G-4 Visa','G-5 Visa','G-5 Visa','H-1/H-3 Visa','H-1/H-3 Visa','H-2A','H-2A','I Visa','I Visa','J-1 Visa','J-1 Visa','L-1 Visa','L-1 Visa','O-1/2 or P-1/3 Visa','O-1/2 or P-1/3 Visa','Q-1 Visa','Q-1 Visa','R-1 Visa','R-1 Visa','T Visa','T Visa','U Visa','U Visa'
                        ]
    ], ...
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use laravel relationships on question model add de follow relationship:

```
public function options()
{
    return $this->hasMany('QuestionOptions', 'question_id', 'id');
}
```

then you can simple query it

```
Question::with('options')->get()
```

and it will return you a model collection.

once with model collection you can use toArray() method and you will get what you want.

you can learn more on laravel documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

and

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections

Comment: I added more table then I don't know how to connect more table? how to do this? like this? `CustomForm::with('question')->Question::with('options')->get()`

Comment: ok got it, `CustomForm::with(['questions', 'question', 'questions.question.options'])->get()->toArray();` one last is, how do I get customerForm.id? on ->where('id', '=', '1')...

Comment: Since id is the primary key you can use `CustomForm::find(1)`